# best way to implement Codeigniter login

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my login controller index function:

```
public function index() {

    $data['title'] = 'Login';
    $this->load->view('login_form', $data);
}
```

then here's my validate_credentials function:

```
public function validate_credentials() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if ($this->user_model->checkUserAccess($this->input->post('username'))) {           // checks if user has access to the site
            if ($this->ldapAuth()) {                                                        // checks if successful authentication with LDAP server
                $email = $this->user_model->getEmail($this->input->post('username'));
                $gpcid = $this->user_model->getUserGPC($this->input->post('username'));
                $this->user_model->updateTimestamp('users', 'DateLastLogin', 'UserID', $this->input->post('username'));
                $data = array (
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'gpcid' => $gpcid,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'is_logged_in' => true 
                    );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('profile');
            } else {                                                                        // unsuccessful login
                $error = "Username and/or Password is incorrect";
                $data['title'] = 'Login';
                $data['message'] = $error;
                $this->load->view('login_form', $data);
            }
        } else {
            $error = "You do not have access to the site";
            $data['title'] = 'Login';
            $data['message'] = $error;
            $this->load->view('login_form', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to just call the index function and pass the error message rather than loading the view multiple times?

```
$data['title'] = 'Login';
$data['message'] = $error;
$this->load->view('login_form', $data);
```

Comment: what about set session for error message and other things.
and redirect them to the index..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading view file you have to redirect it to index function. And use [Session flash data](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata) to achieve this.

Like,

**Controller**

```
$this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', 'Username and/or Password is incorrect' );
redirect('index');
```

To print the message on login_form.php view file,

**View (login_form.php)**

```
<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
       echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
}?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked. :) didn't know that existed.

Comment: Doc's for CI3 and CI2 now moved to here codeigniter official website http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller

```
public function validate_credentials() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if ($this->user_model->checkUserAccess($this->input->post('username'))) {           // checks if user has access to the site
            if ($this->ldapAuth()) {                                                        // checks if successful authentication with LDAP server
                $email = $this->user_model->getEmail($this->input->post('username'));
                $gpcid = $this->user_model->getUserGPC($this->input->post('username'));
                $this->user_model->updateTimestamp('users', 'DateLastLogin', 'UserID', $this->input->post('username'));
                $data = array (
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'gpcid' => $gpcid,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'is_logged_in' => true 
                    );
                $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
                redirect('profile');
            } else {   

                    $userdata = array (
                    'error' =>'Username and/or Password is incorrect',
                    );
                $this->session->set_flashdata($userdata);
                redirect('redirect url here'); // here is your url for index

            }
        } else {

            $userdata = array (
                    'error' =>'You do not have access to the site',
                    );
             $this->session->set_flashdata($userdata);
             redirect('redirect url here'); // here is your url for index
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function loginaction() {

    $this->load->library('session');    

    $a = $this->input->post('email');
    $b = trim($this->input->post('password'));
    $b1 = md5($b);
    $c = 1;

    $data = $this->userdata->userlogin($a, $b1, $c);

    if($data) {

        echo true;

        foreach ($data as $login) {
            $uid = $this->session->set_userdata('logId', $login->usr_id);                                
        } 

    } else {

        echo "Invalid username or password..!!!!";
        $a = $this->input->post('email');

    }

}
```

Comment: Should not be using md5 for passwords any more not secure method.